# What is this iOS error and where is it coming from?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash, runtime-error, key-value-coding

My friend's app is getting an error and I do not know what to do about it.I researched this error and I came across so many different answers, but none of them seems to work.Any help will be appreciated.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: 
'[<RootViewController 0xac80420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value 
 coding-compliant for the key optOutStatusSlider.'
```

Comment: It can be caused by an outlet in your storyboard/NIB, but no such `IBOutlet` in your custom class. Possibly you renamed a control, but the old outlet is still in interface builder.

Comment: Is there any outlet named `optOutStatusSlider` ?

Comment: Yes you are right my friend. Remove all outlets from IB, check the class name of view and file owner and reconnect the outlets. It will solve your issues. If you have not much experience of IB and the crash exixts delete this XIB and re create it, crash will be gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant  There are several duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify your references of your outlets in your XIB/Storyboard, one of them is probably referencing a property that does not exist anymore.